# How to display my records in money digit grouping?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that display in table using MySQL, I set the type to decimal(15,2). How to separate thousands, hundreds, tens and ones? Please help me.. I want to display money records in digit grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the PHP tag that you are using PHP although you do not state this explicitly. To format a number in PHP, use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

Comment: how to encode that? $number = $rows['total_amount'];
number_format($number, 2, '.', ','); just like this?

Comment: If you are using US/ English-style number format with "," as the thousands separator and "." as the decimal separator, `number_format($number, 2)` should suffice

Comment: How can I display the records just like this: 3,232,300.00 ?
I tried the code below but the output is 0.00
number_format($rows['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',')

Comment: @dummydummy I'm not clear what you're asking: can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: I solved my problem,

and this my shorter code.

<?php
$sql2= mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount FROM procurement");
echo'<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
<thead>
<tr><th title="Total Price">Total Amount</th></tr>
</thead>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
 echo'<tr><td>'.number_format($rows['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
?>

I hope it helps to the other beginner like me :)

Comment: @dummydummy Instead of adding your solution as a comment, you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others can see what worked

Answer (score 0):

you can use one custom function like below

```
<?php 
echo formatMoney(1050); # 1,050 
echo formatMoney(1321435.4, true); # 1,321,435.40 
echo formatMoney(10059240.42941, true); # 10,059,240.43 
echo formatMoney(13245); # 13,245 

function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) { 
    if ($fractional) { 
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number); 
    } 
    while (true) { 
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number); 
        if ($replaced != $number) { 
            $number = $replaced; 
        } else { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return $number; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: $money=$rows['total_amount']; echo number_format($money, 2); can I do this way ? How I can connect this format to the value of $rows?

Comment: when I used like that, the display value of column is 0.00, what should I do? please help me

Comment: i think your variable not content any number pls check before call that function

Comment: @dummydummy,it would be glad for me if you will accept my answer.so some one can use it for future reference

Comment: I solved my problem, and this my shorter code. <?php $sql2= mysql_query("SELECT *,SUM(unit_cost*quantity) AS total_amount FROM procurement"); echo'<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1" style="text-transform:uppercase;"> <thead> <tr><th title="Total Price">Total Amount</th></tr> </thead>'; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ echo'<tr><td>'.number_format($rows['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td></tr>'; } echo "</table>"; ?> I hope it helps to the other beginner like me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the php function, which called: [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). It has 4 parameters:

- **number**: The number being formatted.
- **decimals**: Sets the number of decimal points.
- **dec_point**: Sets the separator for the decimal point.
- **thousands_sep**: Sets the thousands separator.

Well, You need the forth parameter - **thousands_sep**. It serves as a separator for thousands.